# iOS - Voiceover issue in tableview alphabetic filters

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I am implementing voiceover in my existing application.

I am using voiceover in the table view alphabet filter. When I click any one of the alphabets from alphabet filter, the corresponding content list is not displayed in the table view.

I just tried how it works in the iPhone contact list. I faced the same problem in the contact list. I don't know if this the issue or this is the normal functionality. Because of contact list also giving the same result.

The following response I'm getting in the voiceover

> table index adjustable swipe up or down with one finger to adjust the value

**Please check the screenshot**

[image]

Please advise and help me to resolve or handle for this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting the expected behavior, especially if it's the same behavior as Contacts.

### VoiceOver's interaction model

VoiceOver uses an interaction model that is based on "focus" and "act". Instead of a single tap to interact with buttons and other control on the screen, a single tap on an element will "focus" on that element. At this point VoiceOver will read information about that element such as its "label", "value" (if any), "traits" (how it behaves), and "hint" (if any).

The user can also swipe left or right with one finger to move focus to the previous or next element. You will find that a lot of VoiceOver's gestures can happen anywhere on the screen. For example, a one finger double tap is used to "activate" an element (for example to press a focused button). In this case it doesn't matter if the double tap happens on the focused element or anywhere else on the screen.

### More specifically about the table view index

The same things apply to the table view index. A single tap on the index will focus the index, treating the entire index as one intractable element. The index has the "adjustable" trait, which is why VoiceOver both reads "adjustable", but also reads an explanation of that interaction: "swipe up or down with one finger to adjust the value".

With the index focused (like in that screenshot) you can swipe up with one finger anywhere on the screen to "increment" the value and swipe down with one finger anywhere on the screen to "decrement" the value. (However, in the case of the table view index, these are inverted to match the scrolling direction).

If you start by (quickly) swiping up with one finger you may notice that nothing happens except that a soft "dong" sound is playing. This lets the user know that the value is at its bounds and cannot be incremented or decremented any further. (You can try the same thing with for example the volume slider in Music (focused the volume slider and swipe up or down with one finger) and notice that the "dong" sound plays when the volume can't go lower/higher).

If you instead swipe down with one finger you may notice that VoiceOver reads "B" and that the table view scrolled down to the "B"-section. Now if you swipe down again it will read "C" and scroll down to that section. At this point you can also swipe up to go up one section again.

#### Some additional information

If you swipe right with one finger (the gesture to navigate to the next element) with the table view index in focus you may note that it changes focus to the first table view cell of the "selected" section. From there, the next and previous elements are the other cells in the table view.

With the table view header or cell in focus, swiping up or down anywhere on the screen with three fingers will scroll the table view up or down, one "page" at a time.

You can read more about VoiceOver and Accessibility on iOS on [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/ios/).

Comment: I got the item chooser list as described at http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/voiceover.html#ItemChooserList but, when I flick right with one finger with the table view index in focus, I never select the first cell of the selected section as you describe : the selected cell is always the one in the middle of the table view approximately. Do you know why ? (tests made on the iphone native screens with iOS12).